# GA not tracking every user

Tags: analytics, real-time-data, user-tracking

I have implemented Google Analytics through GTM on my Site CAPinside.com . But somehow it won't track every user that is on my site. I am able to see the real time traffic through our own Dashboard using Websockets, but the Statistics number does not even come close. 
GA is only tracking a couple hundred users.

Please help me

Comment: Do you track the same thing? eg google tracks users and you track page visits?

Comment: Yes, we currently Track both.